# How to search through data in firebase android from given structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search through data in firebase like here:

[image]

I have already tried, but it not works

```
 //Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(uid).orderByChild("title").startAt(editable.toString()).endAt(editable.toString()+"\uf888");

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("categoreis");
           Query query =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("categoreis").limitToFirst(4).orderByChild("image");
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    list.clear();
               for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
               {

                   for (DataSnapshot ds:data.child("SubAccessories").getChildren())
                   {
                       for (DataSnapshot ds1:ds.getChildren())
                       {
                           //Log.d("checkData1",ds1.toString());

                           //Log.d("checkData1",ds1.child("image").getValue(String.class));

                       }
                   }

               }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `image` as I see in your question, please use the following lines of code but assuming that the `categories` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("categories/Accessories/SubAccessories/Accessories/Grab Bar");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

According to your comment, you should loop through the second `Accessories` node using `getChildren()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("categories/Accessories/SubAccessories/Accessories");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: i want to iterate through all nodes of categories root node then  from that i want to iterate from  as categories -> subAccessories ->heading -> all products

Comment: Please indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: Categories ->  Accessories ->SubbAccessories ->heading ->All Products of all nodes of categories

Comment: but i want to iterate through all node of categories parent node

Comment: You want a list of all items from your database (from all categories)?

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?